# Web3 Batch Requests

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

The documentation on batch requests in web3 is pretty thin. I'm trying to get info on many blocks at once. Do batch requests reduce the number of calls made to the web3 endpoint, or is it just queuing up calls making the same number?

Comment: Maybe you can try ETHQL https://blog.infura.io/ethql-transform-how-you-interact-with-the-ethereum-blockchain-e7a80ed705c9 // https://hack-ethql.infura.io

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, it reduces the number of calls made to the web3 endpoint. It only calls once for every batch.

Here is part of the source code of the `BatchRequest`:

```
RequestManager.prototype.sendBatch = function (data, callback) {
    if (!this.provider) {
        return callback(errors.InvalidProvider());
    }

    var payload = Jsonrpc.toBatchPayload(data);
    this.provider[this.provider.sendAsync ? 'sendAsync' : 'send'](payload, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        if (!_.isArray(results)) {
            return callback(errors.InvalidResponse(results));
        }

        callback(null, results);
    });
};
```

Comment: Hello. Are you sure BatchRequests reduce the number of calls? When im doind a batch request according to this docs https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth.html#id9 i get a call registered for every request in the batch. There are about 9000 requests in the batch. Has it changed, or is there another way of reducing the number of call to the endpoint?

Comment: Batch request do not reduce the number of transactions, you get to sign every call you do and each will get its own hash